# Norm of point evaluation functional

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I am interested in finding a norm of the point evaluation functional which is usually clarified as $$g(t_0)=\int_0^1g(t)\delta(t-t_0) \text{dt}.$$ Here $\delta (t)$ is called a Dirac delta function, $$\delta(t)= \begin{cases}  
0, & t \in [0,1] \setminus {t_0}
\\  
\infty, & t=t_0 \in [0,1]
\end{cases}$$

I have found a similar question ([Norm of integration operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2550527/norm-of-integration-operator)) and I'm curious if I can do the same to evaluate the norm of the integral above?

$$ \Vert A\Vert = \sup_{g\neq 0}\frac{|Ag|}{\Vert g \Vert}$$

Comment: In this case it is easier to just write $A g = g(t_0)$ and forget about the dirac-delta notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, first, as indicated by Arctic Char, the Dirac delta is not needed to speak about the norm of this operator.

But if you want to speak about the Dirac delta, some remarks:

1. it is not a function
2. it is not defined by what you say but either as a measure ($\delta_{t_0}(A) = 1$ iff $t_0\in A$, and $0$ else), as a Radon measure ($\int \varphi\, \delta_{t_0} = \varphi(t_0)$ for $\varphi∈ C^0_0$) or as a distribution (similar definition with $\varphi\in C^\infty_c$: $\delta_{t_0}(\varphi)  = \varphi(t_0)$).

So now, your question is vague since you are not telling what is the norm $\|g\|$. Let us suppose that you want the norm to be the $C^0$ norm for some domain $X$ containing $t_0$. Then, yes, we can indeed do a similar reasoning, even simpler here. For any $g\in C^0(X)$, $\|g\|_{C^0} = \sup_{X} |g|$. Therefore
$$
|\delta_{t_0}(g)| = |g(t_0)| ≤ \|g\|_{C^0}
$$
which shows that the norm of $\delta_{t_0}$ as a linear operator acting on continuous functions is
$$
\|\delta_{t_0}\|_{\mathcal{L}(C^0)} := \sup_{g\neq 0}\frac{|\delta_{t_0}(g)|}{\|g\|_{C^0}} ≤ 1
$$
On the other hand, taking any $f$ continuous verifying $0≤f≤1$ with $f(t_0)=1$ (for example $f(x) = (1-|x-t_0|)_+$), you get
$$
|\delta_{t_0}(f)| = |f(t_0)| = 1 = \|f\|_{C^0}
$$
Therefore you get the inequality is an equality
$$
\|\delta_{t_0}\|_{\mathcal{L}(C^0)} = 1
$$
And this is indeed the value of the integral of the Dirac measure, since it is also $1$. Therefore
$$
\int_X \delta_{t_0} = 1 = \|\delta_{t_0}\|_{\mathcal{L}(C^0)}
$$