# Calculate the norm of Dirac functional $\mathrm{C}[a, b] \longrightarrow \mathbb{K}$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

If $[a, b] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, then the pointevaluation or Dirac functional at $x_0 \in[a, b]$,
$$
\delta_{x_0}: \mathrm{C}[a, b] \longrightarrow \mathbb{K}, \quad \delta_{x_0}(f):=f\left(x_0\right),
$$
is a bounded linear functional on $\left(\mathrm{C}[a, b],\|\cdot\|_{\infty}\right)$ with norm $\left\|\delta_{x_0}\right\|=1$.

It is bounded because $|\delta_{x_0}(f)| = |f(x_0)| \leq \|f\|_{\infty}$. But why its norm $\left\|\delta_{x_0}\right\|=1$?

**My attempt**

Since $|\delta_{x_0}(f)| = |f(x_0)| \leq \|f\|_{\infty}$, we have that
$$\|\delta_{x_0}\| := \sup_{f\neq 0}\frac{|\delta_{x_0}(f)|}{\|f\|} ≤ 1$$
This implies that $\|\delta_{x_0}(f)\| \leq 1$ for each $f \in \mathrm{C}[a, b]$. Moreover, taking $f = \chi_{\{x_0\}}$, where $\chi_A$ is the characteristic function of the set $A$, we get $\|\delta_{x_0}(f)\| = 1$.

Comment: What have you tried? What's the simplest example of continuous function you can think of, and what happens when applying $\delta_{x_0}$ to them?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3860823

Comment: This is a case where you want to just write down the definitions of the norm of an operator and $\|f\|_\infty.$ It will become pretty easy.

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited the post  with my attempt.

Comment: This is almost it, except that $\chi_{\{x_0\}}$ is not a continuous function. Can you think of some way to fix this?